# How do I edit the innertext of a node in an XML file in Visual Basic?

Tags: xml, vb.net, basic

I've been trying to create a simple scores system for a quiz I'm making in Visual Basic. I started off with a basic XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Scores>
  <test1>13</test1>
</Scores>
```

I managed to open the XML file up and print a specific node's inner text and this is my code so far (file path has been omitted):

```
Imports System.Xml
Module Module1


    Sub Main()
        Dim test = XDocument.Load("filepath")

        Dim test5 As String = test.Descendants("test1").Value()
        Console.WriteLine(test5)
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

My only problem now is trying to edit the inner text of a specific node. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with an `XmlDocument` and `XmlNode`.

```
Imports System.Xml

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim xmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
        Dim test1Node As XmlNode = Nothing

        xmlDoc.Load("filePath.xml")
        test1Node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Scores/test1")

        Console.WriteLine(test1Node.InnerText)
        test1Node.InnerText = "42"
        xmlDoc.Save("filePath.xml")

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. This is way easier.